# Rackspace CloudFiles .NET library: delimiter query parameter?

Tags: asp.net, api, rackspace-cloud, cloudfiles

Is the 'delimiter' query parameter implemented in the c# (.NET) library? I could not find it.
Ref.: http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/List_Objects-d1e1284.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes implemented and closed [issue #52 on Github](https://github.com/rackspace/csharp-cloudfiles/issues/52)

[Download here](https://github.com/downloads/rackspace/csharp-cloudfiles/csharp-cloudfiles-DOTNETv3.5-bin-2.0.0.16.zip)